# ie7 li under li instead of the same height

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

the li's of my table are been placed one below the other in ie7 and not in the same line like all the other browsers.

what should I add to the li or ul definition,I have a possibly to add a different css only for ie7 if that can help.

link:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/107452929/ie7/index.htm

Comment: Post your code *here*, otherwise the question is nonsensical if you should ever delete your Dropbox, or for users unable to follow that link.

Comment: Why dont you accept answers to your previous questions before you ask new ones? I've took time to resolve your previous question but you dint acknowledge it still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that Internet Explorer can only apply `display: inline-block` to elements that are '*naturally*' in-line.

The work-around, for IE, would seem to be to use `float:left` instead.

Although another solution seems to be using a separate conditionally-included CSS for IE:

```
<!--[if ie lte 7]>
    .liElementsClass,
    li {
        display: inline;
        zoom: 1;
    }
<![end if]-->
```

Reference:

- ['display inline-block cross-browser solutions,' at Hanami Design](http://hanamidesign.com/blog/display-inline-block-cross-browser-solutions/).
- [Quirksmode, compatibility table for `display: inline-block`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#t03).

Comment: after reading the Hanami Design article I manage to solve the issue with ie7

Answer (score 0):

try adding `display:block;` to your `<li>`

Comment: I try but the problem still continue ,it's look like every li get a width of the all ul and that why the li are not in the same line.